# How to loop through API link using foreach loop?

Tags: laravel, api, loops, email, foreach

I have an array of emails that are used by an api to send multiple emails in one go

The array I recieve through the controller are like this:

```
email_users:["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com","email3@gmail.com"]
```

now I want to loop through the api, repeating the api url with each email from the array.
I tried looping but the result gave me the url link containing all email from the array
like:

```
 ...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email1@gmail.com.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com,&subject=asd&message=asd
```

now i want to loop the api url containing each email from the array in this format:

```
...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email1@gmail.com,&subject=asd&message=asd
...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email2@gmail.com,&subject=asd&message=asd
...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email3@gmail.com,&subject=asd&message=asd
```

here's my current code:

```
$emails = $request->email_users;
$emailadd = '';
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $emailadd .= $email.",";
    $subject = $request->subject;
    $subject_encode = urlencode($subject);
    $msg = $request->message;
    $msg_encode = urlencode($msg);
                    
$url = 'https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email='.$emailadd.'&subject='.$subject_encode.'&message='.$msg_encode;
}
```

UPDATE:
I send this api using this method:

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $emailadd .= $email.",";
    $subject = $request->subject;
    $subject_encode = urlencode($subject);
    $msg = $request->message;
    $msg_encode = urlencode($msg);
                    
$url = Http::accept('application/json')->withToken($token)->post('https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email='.$emailadd.'&subject='.$subject_encode.'&message='.$msg_encode))
}
```

Then if the API url is successful, the pages returns to the page with success message using if else condition:

```
if($url->successful()) {
                    return back()->with('flash_message_success','SMS Sent!');
                } else {
                    return back()->with('flash_message_error','SMS Sending Failed!');
                }
```

Comment: Hint `explode()`?

Comment: have you tried sending them as an array in the url ? `com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email[]=email1@gmail.com.com&email[]=email2@gmail.com&email[]=email3@gmail.com&subject=asd&message=asd`

Comment: I haven't tried it but I doubt if it will work since we can't put multiple email in the api url, only one email is allowed on the url

Comment: hi ror, if you wanted multiple `$url` instances, why did you only return single `$url` and concatenated even? you can curl it inside the loop if you need it to be.

Comment: I only use it to see what $url contains, for debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you have request like this :

```
{
    "subject":"asd",
    "message":"asd",
    "email_users":[
        "email1@gmail.com",
        "email2@gmail.com",
        "email3@gmail.com"
    ]
}
```

You can transform using `foreach` :

```
$urls = [];

foreach ($request->email_users as $email) {
    $urls[] = 'https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?' . http_build_query([
        'email' => $email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'message' => $request->message,
    ]);
}

dd($urls);
```

Output :

```
array:3 [
  0 => "https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email1%40gmail.com&subject=asd&message=asd"
  1 => "https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email2%40gmail.com&subject=asd&message=asd"
  2 => "https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?email=email3%40gmail.com&subject=asd&message=asd"
]
```

##### Update (from comment)

When you use Laravel HTTP Client, you can use :

```
foreach ($request->email_users as $email) {
    $params = [
        'email' => $email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'message' => $request->message,
    ];

    Http::accept('application/json')
        ->withToken($token)
        ->post('https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php', $params)
}

return back();
```

Comment: Hi Wahyu, this seems to be the answer im looking for, but I encountered a problem. I forgot to mention that im posting the url using this format: $urls[] = Http::accept('application/json')->withToken($token)->post('https://...com/SEND_EMAIL.php?' . http_build_query([....
if($urls[]->successful()) { return back(); } else { return back(); }
now it gives me this error of call to function successful on array()

Comment: Please update your question. I can't read code from your comment.

Comment: I update my answer. But, please note, I did not explain the `if-else` condition, because you did not explain in detail how to proceed when one of the data fails.

Comment: hello again Wahyu, the first answer you gave is the answer I was looking for, the api we're using were having problems yesterday so I can't reply if the answer you gave is working or not. The API was fixed today so I can verify that the first answer you gave was the working answer. Thankyou so much! :)

Comment: I have a question. I have written an API using Laravel Passport and utilizing the API on the same server but with another subdomain. 
=> First, I get the data from the table, which is 258.
=> Then run the API inside the loop. 
But here is what happened.
The API returns the data for the first 50 records, then the next 30 nulls, the next 40 with data, the next 10 nulls, and so on.

URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ui9NBmdDETXf4ktJlGnbYxIhWiblh2xT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @salmanifrahim I think, it's better for you to make a question than write in the comments because there are no details

Comment: @WahyuKristianto, I already created a separate question about two weeks ago, but no one answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831397/laravel-passport-doesnt-bring-results-in-foreach-loop-sometimes