# Laravel Passport doesn't bring results in foreach loop sometimes

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to get data with laravel passport API, which returns null for some IDs in a foreach loop. But if I pick that Id and try to get individual results, it works fine. When we have 50 or more records, it starts to create problems.

Code Sample:

```
    public function name()
    {
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        try{

            $all_product_prices = SProductNcrPadPrice::select('id', 'product_id', 'sku')->get();

            if (!empty($all_product_prices)) {
                foreach ($all_product_prices as $key => $row_signal_product_price) {

                        $ncr_token = $this->createNcrPadsToken();
                        $response_get_list = Http::withToken($ncr_token)->get($this->base_url.'/product/get_list?queryString={"product_id": "'.$row_signal_product_price->sku.'"}');
                        $products_list_get = json_decode($response_get_list->body(), true);
info($products_list_get);
                    if(!empty($products_list_get["data"]) && count($products_list_get["data"]) > 0){
                        echo "<pre>";
                        echo "In";                  
                    }else{
                        echo "<pre>";
                        echo "Out";
                    }
                }
            }
        
        }catch(HttpEmptyResponse $e)
        {
            abort(500, 'contact support');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello again. What is `createNcrPadsToken`?

Comment: It gets the token from the API first then I pass the token to the API to get the data

Comment: Does each iteration, use a different token? If so, I don't think it's necessary. Simply create 1 token, then use it repeatedly until it expires.